# How to create a distortion effect in the middle part of a text?

Tags: vector, logo

I'm a real newbie in design and I need to make a logo. For that I'd like to reproduce a pretty simple effect I saw on Pinterest but I can't find out how to do it. If someone could tell me which tools to use I'd really appreciate it.

Here is the logo I'd like to reproduce with my own typo (a real simple box logo type font) my question is about the little deformation effect on the letters :

[image: logo]

I can use Adobe tools or others if you have some to suggest me, so you can just tell me the easiest way I'll find out how to get it. Sorry if this question has already been asked I didn't find it but I'm not english speaking so I might lack the keywords for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Illustrator

- Draw a rectangle over the outlined text

[image: rectangle]

- Select the rectangle
- **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Divide Objects Below**

[image: divide]

- **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Select the middle shapes

[image: middle]

- **Menu Effect** > **Warp** > **Flag**

[image: Warp]

**Result**

[image]